# What replaces Notification.Kind in RxJava2

Tags: java, rx-java2

In RxJava it was possible to do:

```
Observable<Notification<Integer>> notifications = Observable
    .just(3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0)
    .concatMapDelayError(x -> fromCallable(() -> 100 / x))
    .materialize();

List<Notification.Kind> kinds = notifications
    .map(Notification::getKind)
    .toList()
    .toBlocking()
    .single();

assertThat(kinds).containsExactly(OnNext, OnNext, OnNext, OnError);
```

What replaces this in RxJava2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtaining the `Observable<Notification<T>>` is the same as RxJava 1.

However `Notification.Kind` no longer exists. It is possible to define your own `enum NotificationKind` and mapping the correct value based on `notification.isOnNext` and the other corresponding methods.